# Почему addEventListener для кастомного события вешается на id для которого нет dispatchEvent?

Tags: javascript, javascript-events

Почему событие `addEventListener` вешается на rabbit ?

Разве после `let event = new CustomEvent...` не должно быть `rabbit.dispatchEvent(event)` ?

Как этот листенер вообще работает?

```js
function hide() {
  let event = new CustomEvent("hide", {
    cancelable: true
  });
  if (!rabbit.dispatchEvent(event)) {
    alert('отменено обработчиком');
  } else {
    rabbit.hidden = true;
  }
}

rabbit.addEventListener("hide", function(event) {
  if (confirm("вызвать preventDefault?")) {
    event.preventDefault();
  }
});
```

```html
<pre id="rabbit">
    |\   /|
     \|_|/
     /. .\
    =\_Y_/=
     {>o<}
  </pre>
<button onclick="hide()">Hide()</button>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не совсем понял ход ваших мыслей. Но постараюсь объяснить работу кастомного события на странице.

1. Не буду заострять внимание на страницу с `rabbit` и `Hide()` button. Есть и всё
2. Обекты создались запускаем основной скрипт
3. Объявление метода `hide` который вызывается на событие click кнопки (button)
4. Подписываемся на кастомное событие "hide" rabbit.

Далее при нажатии кнопки вызывается метод `hide()`. Которое создаёт `event` и передает его вызовом  `rabbit.dispatchEvent` на строке `if ( !rabbit.dispatchEvent(event) ) {` который вызывает обработчик события `hide`.

**Почему событие addEventListener вешается на rabbit?** -- Вешайте куда угодно. Не забывайте диспачить куда нужно.

```html
<pre id="rabbit">
    |\   /|
     \|_|/
     /. .\
    =\_Y_/=
     {>o<}
  </pre>
  <button onclick="hide()" id="norabit">Hide()</button>

  <script>
    function hide() {
      let event = new CustomEvent("hide", {
        cancelable: true
      });
      if ( !norabit.dispatchEvent(event) ) {
        alert('отменено обработчиком');
      } else {
        rabbit.hidden = true;
      }
    }

    norabit.addEventListener("hide", function(event) {
      if ( confirm("вызвать preventDefault?") ) {
        event.preventDefault();
      }
    });
  </script>
```

**Разве после "let event = new CustomEvent..." не должно быть rabbit.dispatchEvent(event)?** -
У вас имменно так и делается. `event = new ...   if ( !rabbit.dispatchEvent(event) ) {`

**Как этот листенер вообще работает?** - Как и все листенеры. Если приходит событие на которое он подписан, то он передаёт его в обработчик eventHandler.

Comment: понятно. я почему то подумал что встроке с if это условие только проверяется, но не выполняется)